# How to give an error output when there's not enough values given to input in Python?

Tags: python

There's a part of my schoolwork. I need to give an error output when user doesn't give an second input, but as you know python gives an error itself when you don't give the second output. Is there any way to do that or do I have to change my implementation?
I have to check the second argument that's why I am getting the arguments seperately.
I tried this but obviously it didn't work:

```
 option, person = input("Choose an option and person: ").split()
    if person==None:
            print("Missing argument")
```

Comment: You need a `try` `except` block.

Comment: thank you so much, going to try that now

Comment: You can first check the length of array after split and only when you have 2 - assign values, otherwise give an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
try:
    option, person = input("Choose an option and person: ").split()
    print(option, person)
except ValueError:
    print("Missing argument")
```

Comment: thank you so much! this was the most efficent answer so far:)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Treat the "rest" part as a list and check if its length is zero.

```
option, *person = input("Choose an option and person: ").split()
if len(person) == 0:
  print("Missing argument")
```

Answer (score 0):

either wrap the line that throws an error in a `try: except` block or don't do the tuple unpacking on the same line:

```py
data = input("Choose an option and person: ").split()
if len(data) != 2:
   raise ValueError("RELEVANT ERROR HANDLING HERE")
else:
   option, person = data
```

note that typing "a me b" also causes problems so checking that the length is exactly 2 is relevant instead of just `>1`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help!

```
data=input("Choose A and B: ").split()
if len(data)!=2:
    print("Missing argument")
else:
    A=data[0]
    B=data[1]

print(A)
print(B)
```